# Can we use shadcn without framework?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadcnui

Is there a way to use Shadcn components in a simple project without any framework?

I tried Vite and manual installation structures. They create `.vue` and `.tsx` files for components. I want to know if there is a way to have `.js` files for components.

Comment: ["To opt-out of TypeScript, you can use the tsx flag in your components.json file."](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation).

Comment: ...but, note, they're still _React_ components. You can't use them anywhere except as part of a React app.